# cocoa: Is there any way to do paste action in another app in sandbox

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, sandbox

out app was rejected because we use System Events to call cmd+v in another app. I know that I can't do CGEventPostToPSN inside sandbox, too. 
Is there any way to do paste action (or call cmd+v in another app) and send app to mac app store? Have anyone faced this problem?

Comment: Does another app from your company too?

Comment: No, we want to paste to any app. Just call cmd+v there.

Comment: Just to add data to `NSPasteboard` or to paste it too?

Comment: To paste it to. Adding data is easy, more complex task it to activate "cmd+v" in another app. Without sandbox it's easy, about 4-5 ways to do it. But with it all this ways is illegal. I tries to set access to System Events in entitlements, but it's illegal, too, so app was rejected.

Answer (score 1):

Apple will definitely reject the app which is trying to paste some data into another application textfields. But there may be some ways to accomplish your task:

1. The application, you're trying to communicate with is application you're developing too. In this case you should use some kind of distributed notifications (it's like simple NSNotificationCenter, but for several applications communicating to). There're another technics, please look at this [wonderful article](http://nshipster.com/inter-process-communication/) from Mattt Thompson.
2. The second application is a random one. In this case you may use [NSSharingService](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSSharingService_Class/) or [NSSharingServicePicker](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSSharingServicePicker_Class/). This is some equivalent of UIActivityViewController from the cocoa-touch if you familiar. It will work if only the another application is set to work the service.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. And there no way to paste into any app, that could complete "cmd+v" command, while being in sandbox?

Comment: @AlexZimin I think there isn't a way to force another application to perform the "cmd+v" command.